# Cannot Resolve Symbol "layout_listitem"

Tags: android, android-studio

I typed it correctly

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
```

The xml file is not empty and it exists, a constraint one in a recycler view that i am trying to build from a youtube tutorial codingwithmitch, It says it cannot resolve the symbol yet it is clearly there! I tried the shortcut to create the xml of the missing filename but it still gives the same error. What gives?

[image: problem screenshot]

Comment: clean-rebuild-restart.

Comment: what usually causes the error? restarting atm

Comment: wow it worked!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi bro Just try invalidate cache and restart, clean project and rebuild. Let me know if it exists still.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are importing the right `R` class

```
import com.app.package.R;
```

`com.app.package` to be replaced with your package

And when inflting your view don't add `.xml` extension just your layout id

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
```

`build > clean project` & `build > Rebuild project` then try to run your app